# SharePoint 2013 Parallel workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013 designer to implment workflow.
Requirement : parallel approval happens by 3 different groups.
Scenario: I am stuck how to implement if any one rejects workflow should be rejected completely.
What option should I select for outcome to achieve this logic.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way to achieve this is to set wait for particular response .
and set outcome to wait for rejected. So that Workflow will automatically send mail to user who have not responded yet and also removes task items.

Hope this helps some one.

Comment: Is this workflow on Sharepoint Workflow 2013? Can you elaborate more?